# Is wave energy or matter?

Tags: energy, waves, matter

There  are  many  types  of  waves. I  want  to  ask  that  how  do  they  behave? are  they  matter  or  energy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first waves observed were water waves, then with the discovery of  differential equations it was found that many physical quantities obey these wave equations, as sound waves, seismic waves, electromagnetic waves. All these are within classical physics and what is "waving" is the amplitude of the effect, i.e. the energy which propagates sinusoidally, according to the wave equations solutions.

Then quantum mechanics became necessary to explain the microcosm of atoms and molecules, and it was found that the data were modeled  by differential equations, which had the form of wave equations, but what is"waving" there, is the probability of finding an atom/electron/molecule at a specific (x,y,z,t).

So there exist not only classical energy transport waves, but also quantum mechanical probability density waves, in accumulations of data from the microcosm, as with the single electron double slit observations which show [wave interferences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles). These come from the sinusoidal solutions of wave equations, as for example the [Schrodinger one.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation)

[image: dblssliele]

Note that a single electron is whole  in one point on the recording screen. The accumulation of electrons shows the wave nature of the probability density. Collectively, with many electrons, the mass distribution of the last screen shot would  show a wave nature if weighted, but it is derived from the individual electron's probability density distribution.

Answer (score 1):

A wave is simply a disturbance in space that propagates in time. So it has a definite energy and the "thing" that is "waving"(being disturbed) could be matter, for example, as in water waves (water) and sound waves (air) or it could be energy, for example, electromagnetic waves (oscillations of electric and magnetic fields).